# Mongoose schema within schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

How can I add a schema to another schema? This doesn't seem to be valid:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name        : String,
    app_key     : String,
    app_secret  : String
})



var TaskSchema = new Schema({
    name            : String,
    lastPerformed   : Date,
    folder          : String,
    user            : UserSchema
})
```

I checked the website and it shows how to declare it for an array but not for single.

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing a join between two collections or do you want to store them on top of task?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. The simplest is just this:

```
var TaskSchema = new Schema({
    name            : String,
    lastPerformed   : Date,
    folder          : String,
    user            : Schema.ObjectId
});
```

Then you just have to make sure your app is writing that id and using it in queries to fetch "related" data as necessary.

This is fine when searching tasks by user id, but more cumbersome when querying the user by task id:

```
// Get tasks with user id
Task.find({user: user_id}, function(err, tasks) {...});

// Get user from task id
Task.findById(id, function(err, task) {
  User.findById(task.user, function(err, user) {
    // do stuff with user
  }
}
```

Another way is to take advantage of Mongoose's [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) feature to simplify your queries. To get this, you could do the following:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name        : String,
    app_key     : String,
    app_secret  : String,
    tasks       : [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Task'}] // assuming you name your model Task
});

var TaskSchema = new Schema({
    name            : String,
    lastPerformed   : Date,
    folder          : String,
    user            : {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'} // assuming you name your model User
});
```

With this, your query for all users, including arrays of their tasks might be:

```
User.find({}).populate('tasks').run(function(err, users) {
  // do something
});
```

Of course, this means maintaining the ids in both places. If that bothers you, it may be best to stick to the first method and just get used to writing more complex (but still simple enough) queries.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. I have another question but maybe I should create a new question.

Comment: `.run()` was replaced by `.exec()` as it seems

Comment: another [link][1], with [populate][2], might help you too.


  [1]: http://gistflow.com/posts/46-mongoose-populate
  [2]: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: type: Schema.Types.ObjectId

Answer (score 16):

As of version 4.2.0, mongoose supports single subdocuments.

From [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html):

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  // Array of subdocuments
  children: [childSchema],
  // Single nested subdocuments. Caveat: single nested subdocs only work
  // in mongoose >= 4.2.0
  child: childSchema
});
```

Answer (score 11):

What about this simple solution?

```
var TaskSchema = new Schema({
    name            : String,
    lastPerformed   : Date,
    folder          : String,
    user            : {
        name        : String,
        app_key     : String,
        app_secret  : String
    }
 })
```

Comment: Wouldn't this eliminate the ability to query users directly, and also potentially lead to user objects being duplicated across many tasks? If you were going to flatten the data model to just one structure, I would think you'd want UserSchema to be a parent of tasks rather than the other way around.

Comment: makes the code look messy. Hence wanted the schema within the schema

Comment: This is not a scalable solution for Schema that use multiple or large schema embedded within them. I think OP (and I) want non-trivial solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name        : String,
    app_key     : String,
    app_secret  : String
});
var TaskSchema = new Schema({
name            : String,
lastPerformed   : Date,
folder          : String,
user            :{
type            : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref             : 'User', // Reference the 'User' model
} 
});
const User=mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
const Tasks=mongoose.model('Tasks',Taskschema);
```

The **user field** in the **TaskSchema** is set as a reference to the **User model**. By using **mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId** as the data type, you indicate that the user field will store the **ObjectId** of a User document.

The **ref: 'User'** property indicates that the user field references the User model. When you save a Task document, you will need to provide the _id (ObjectId) of an existing User document to link the task to the appropriate user.