# How to save schemas inside schemas using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is there a way of saving a schema inside another one? Because I was trying to do it with no results since the embedded schema was not saved. Here are my schemas:

```
var event = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    location: String
});

var user = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    events: [event]
});

var User = new mongoose.model('User', user);
```

I used the Model.save() function of mongoose, but I don't know the existence of any other function to save documents to the mongo database. Also, when I query the database and retrieve the data saved, it shows `events: []`, so no data was saved. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** This is the code I used to create the object:

```
var kratos = new user({
    name: 'Kratos',
    events: [
        {
            name: 'Kill gods',
            location: 'Bay shore'
        },{
            name: 'Collect orbs',
            location: 'Olympus'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737082/mongoose-schema-within-schema

Comment: That link asks how to add a schema to another one. I already did it, my main problem is that it is not being stored in the db.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this as a simple solution though?

```
var user = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    events: {
        name: String,
        location: String
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the User model slightly to the following:

```
var User = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    events: []
});
```

Then, you'll need to create the new event object. Something like this will do:

```
var events = [];

var newEvent = new Event({
    name : "Name",
    location: "Place"
});

events.push(newEvent);

var kratos = new User({
    name: 'Kratos',
    events: events
});
```