# How to design mongodb schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am recently learning node, wanna write a node app with mongodb.

I have a UserSchema like this.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    jwt: String,
  },
  { timestamps: Date },
);
```

then I added a messages property?

```
 const MessageSchema = new Schema(
  {
    message: String,
  },
  { timestamps: Date },
);


const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    jwt: String,
    messages: [MessageSchema]
  },
  { timestamps: Date },
);
const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema)
module.exports = User;
```

the thing is when I create a message, I wanna be added to this user's messages array,
and I still can export a schema that I can do `messages.find()` to query the database for all the messages.

or I think each message should have a property of `owner` to point to the user.
But how can I approach this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose schema within schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737082/mongoose-schema-within-schema)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this. I never had problem working by this way.

```
var mongoose = require ("mongoose");

var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Example1: 'String',
    Example2: 'String',
    Example3: 'Number',
    Example4:'string',

});
var model = mongoose.model ('myExample', mySchema);,
```

If you want to learn more about it, you can try with some this links:
[link-1](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)
[link-2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/)
[link-3](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications)
[link-4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose).

Hope it help you.