# How create nested mongoDb schema in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i'm trying to design mongoose shema for users cleaner and customer, they have some common fields e.g. name, but also have extra (different fields) client(rating) and customer number. I'm not sure that my design is good.

I've created separate userSchema for customer and cleaner, and created separate address schema.

```
// User Schema
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

 // AddressSchema
 const AddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   city: {
    type: String,
    required: true
   },
  street: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

// CustomerSchema
 const CustomerSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  name: UserSchema,
  address: AddressSchema 
 });

// CleanerSchema
const CleanerSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
 name: UserSchema,
 rating: {
  type: Number,
  required: true
 }

});
```

My schema doesn't work. Could you give best practice example for my schema?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would define your Customer and Cleaner schemas. I don't think it's necessary to create the separate name and address schemas.

```
const CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  address: {
    city: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    street: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
});

const CleanerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
});
```

Comment: But there are more common fields (name, surname, password, address and so on), Moreover, my purpose is to learn, how to create separate schemas, if you can, please help me

Comment: The top answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737082/mongoose-schema-within-schema provides some good information about various approaches to nesting schemas and in which cases this is necessary. Hope that gives you a starting point!