# Populate linked reference in Listview Flutter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I need to populate Referenced database in **ListView**. In this case I need to Show the **Designation Name** of the User which is the reference in **User Model**. How do I call it in Flutter to display the Designation name?

[image]

> My UserSchema is

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
'username' : String,
'role_id' : Number,
'designation_id' : {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Designation'
},
'login_id' : String,
'password' : String,
'status' : String,
'company_id' : {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company'
},
'enable_login' : Number,
'creation_user_id' : {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}, 'update_user_id' : {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
'creation_dt' : Date,
'update_dt' : Date});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

> My Destination Model is:

```
var DesignationSchema = new Schema({
'name' : String,
'designation_id' : Number,
'company_id' : {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company'
},
'creation_user_id' : {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
'update_user_id' : {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
'creation_dt' : Date,
'update_dt' : Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Designation', DesignationSchema);
```

User Controller List is:

```
list: function (req, res) {
    UserModel.find(function (err, Users) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Error when getting User.',
                error: err
            });
        }
        return res.json(Users);
    });
},
```

> In Flutter I created a Service for getting all Users

```
static Future<Users> getAllUsers() async{
try{
  final response = await http.get(BASE_URL + USERS);

  if(response.statusCode == 200){
    return parseUsers(response.body);
  }else{
    return Users();
  }

}catch(e){
  print('Error ${e.toString()}');
  return Users();
}
}


static Users parseUsers (String responseBody){
final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

List<User> users = parsed.map<User>((json) => User.fromJson(json)).toList();

Users _users = Users();
_users.users = users;

return _users;
}
```

> Showing it in Flutter via

```
Text(users.users[index].username,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'Roboto',),)

Text("Email: ${users.users[index].login_id}", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 12,fontFamily: 'Roboto',))

Text("Designation: Estimate Engineer", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87,fontSize: 12,fontFamily: 'Roboto',)),
```

Thank you for your Support.

Comment: can you please be clear with the question. I mean I am not able to understand. You are ready displaying designation right?

Comment: I want to populate designation data which is in different Schema, and is referenced to User Schema via is an ObjectId reference.

Comment: there are 2 Schemas, User and Designation. Designation is referenced in User via ObjectId reference. Now How should I display data from both Schemas in Flutter in a single ListItem.

Comment: okay, so you need to create a designation of type List in user model in a flutter.I hope this help if no please let me know I will post an example as asnwer

Comment: Do you mean to change this type?

'designation_id' : {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Designation'
    },

Please post a detailed example as I'm new to flutter. Thanks for your time and support.

Comment: okay sure give me some time, and can have access to the Base URL I mean just to check response in postman.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204095/discussion-between-hasnen-tai-and-nouman-rasheed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to change the response and implement the schema inside schema concept

here is the link which talks about the schema inside schema on stack overflow
**link :**  [Mongoose schema within schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737082/mongoose-schema-within-schema)

Your response should look like this.

```
{
    "_id": "5dee58cba34fa96a09d1f049",
    "username": "Moin",
    "role_id": 1,
    "designation_id": {
        "_id": "5dee57d4a34fa96a09d1f047",
        "name": "Administrator",
        "designation_id": 1,
        "company_id": "5dee54681fc99665221ec960",
        "creation_user_id": "5dee2a859eae3e0a98109d81",
        "update_user_id": "5dee2a859eae3e0a98109d81",
        "creation_dt": null,
        "update_dt": null,
        "__v": 0
        },
    "login_id": "moin@email.com",
    "password": "moin123",
    "status": "1",
    "company_id": "5dee54681fc99665221ec960",
    "enable_login": 1,
    "creation_user_id": "5dee2a859eae3e0a98109d81",
    "update_user_id": "5dee2a859eae3e0a98109d81",
    "creation_dt": null,
    "update_dt": null,
    "__v": 0
    },
```

Insted of storing a ID you should store the whole schema to esaily get the designation,

Hope this helps.