# Find Object and Update by pushing to nested Array in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created a Mongoose Model which holds nested arrays `exercises`>`history`>`data`. I want to make a put request and push an Object, consisting of the time the data was `createdAt` as well as an array of the Users `data` to the `history` of the `exercise` that was run. However, the following attempt did not work:

```
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.user.id, "exercises.title": req.body.exercise_title },
    { $push: { "exercises.$.history": { data: [1,2,3,4,5] } } }
  );
```

My Schema looks as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userName:{
        type: String,
        required: true},
    exercises:[{
        title:{
            type: String,
        },
        history: [{
            createdAt: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            },
            data: []
        }]
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

I have no clue why my query is not working

Comment: Keep in mind [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) function returns the same object before update was applied, have you seen what `console.log()` shows up?. When it comes to Schema within Schema I'd use the reference to another Schema like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737082/mongoose-schema-within-schema).

Comment: @JoseVasquez console.log() returns a whole lot of stuff. But even if findOneAndUpdate returns the old object, the next time that Object is used, the new value should be seen, right? I initially used another Schema but finding two schemas and having to get the data for the same user twice seems like a hassle. It additionally requires me to write more functions when a user deletes his account and such

Comment: @JoseVasquez I checked out the link you gave me. Seems like a good idea maybe. The data is quite bulky too. But then again, how would i implement finding and pushing to the exercise Schema?

Comment: To do so, you should create 2 extra schemas. **ExerciseSchema** and **HistorySchema** following the steps in the post I mentioned before so the only document you have to worry about is the HistorySchema and update that document with the desired data. Let me know if that works for you. Otherwise I can post an answer following the steps as a workaround.